# Array output questions and its asnwers

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So below I have an array that I need to grab data out of I need to output it in a foreach loop:

Question: How to make a tea

Answers:
- tea bag
- tea bag water milk sugar

Question: What is my name

Answers:
- levi
- mark

Array outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [260]=>
  object(Question)#16 (3) {
    ["answers"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(Answer)#18 (5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(3) "144"
        ["answer"]=>
        string(4) "levi"
        ["questionId"]=>
        string(3) "260"
        ["correct"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["quizId"]=>
        string(2) "33"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(Answer)#19 (5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(3) "143"
        ["answer"]=>
        string(4) "mark"
        ["questionId"]=>
        string(3) "260"
        ["correct"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["quizId"]=>
        string(2) "33"
      }
    }
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "260"
    ["question"]=>
    string(15) "What is my name"
  }
  [259]=>
  object(Question)#17 (3) {
    ["answers"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(Answer)#20 (5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(3) "142"
        ["answer"]=>
        string(7) "tea bag"
        ["questionId"]=>
        string(3) "259"
        ["correct"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["quizId"]=>
        string(2) "33"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(Answer)#21 (5) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(3) "141"
        ["answer"]=>
        string(24) "tea bag water milk sugar"
        ["questionId"]=>
        string(3) "259"
        ["correct"]=>
        string(1) "0"
        ["quizId"]=>
        string(2) "33"
      }
    }
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "259"
    ["question"]=>
    string(15) "How to make tea"
  }
}
```

Would be grateful for the help

my start but doesn't work at all just an idea:

```
$questions =  Quiz::OutputQuestions($id);

foreach($questions as $question) {
    echo 'Question: ' . $question['id']['question'];
    echo 'Answers: <br />';

    foreach($answers as $answer) {
          echo '- Answer <br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: will you please add up the Array output string here instead of uploading an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have objects and not arrays inside your top-level array $questions. So you can try this code:

```
$questions =  Quiz::OutputQuestions($id);

foreach($questions as $question) {
    echo 'Question: ' . $question->question;
    echo 'Answers: <br />';

    foreach($question->answers as $answer) {
          echo '- ' . $answer->answer;
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```